# ajax requests wrong URL

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-headers

I have page `url/index.php` which has a ajax request in it for `url/submit.php`.  On most computers it works fine, but I have a client who's computer request url header is from `url/index.php/submit.php` instead of `url/submit.php`.  Below is a short example of the JS used for the AJAX request.  I'm not sure why it's making incorrect request substitution.  It is occurs on both safari and chrome, but not on other computers in the same household.

### AJAX request

```
req=new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('POST','submit.php');                                                                req.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json;  charset=UTF-8');
req.onload=function(resp){
    if (resp.target.status==200){
          do something....
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the URL in the address bar. Probably on the computer where it's failing it's `url/index.php`, and on all the others its `url`. Changing the ajax url to `/submit.php` should make it work everywhere.

Comment: @nick I did try having him go to `url/` and I tried going to `/index.php` and making the request.  Did not fix the issue and  I wasn't able to reproduce the error.  using `/submit.php` doesn't work because it isn't the top directory for the url.

Comment: The issue is that the ajax request URL is relative to the current URL.  So if the current URL ends in `index.php`, the ajax request will go to `url/index.php/submit.php`. To fix this you need to make the ajax URL absolute, if this isn't the top level then include the parts of the path necessary into the URL to make it a top-level path.

Comment: @nick I guess the question is, why is this computer the only one that's too dumb to figure out the right relative paths.  I can't think of a setting that would change that on a web browser.